# Lines aren't read from file every time

Tags: c#, xaml, text-files

I'm beginner with C# and XAML.

In my app I read lines of text to list like this:

```
string path = "ms-appx:///" + _index + ".txt";
StorageFile sampleFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(path));
_stopsList = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(sampleFile, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
```

And I put this to *combobox2*:

```
comboBox2.ItemsSource = routesList[comboBox.SelectedIndex]._stopsList;
```

One time I run my app in debug mode, *combobox2* is correctly filled with the lines from file (like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8atb.png), but for example next time when I run my app, *combobox2* is empty ([2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYJPc.png)) and next to *_stopsList* appears *Count: 0*. Content in *combobox2* doesn't appear every time.

BusRoute class:

```
class BusRoute
{
    public BusRoute(string name, int index)
    {
        Name = name;
        _index = index;
        GetStopsList();
    }

    public async void GetStopsList()
    {
        string path = "ms-appx:///" + _index + ".txt";
        StorageFile sampleFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(path));
        _stopsList = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(sampleFile, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _routeName; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                _routeName = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public IList<string> _stopsList = new List<string>();
    private string _routeName;
    private int _index;
}
```

MainPage:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.DataContext = this;
        this.InitializeComponent();

        routesList.Add(new BusRoute("Laszki – Wysocko - Jarosław", 1));
        routesList.Add(new BusRoute("Tuchla - Bobrówka - Jarosław", 2));

        this.comboBox.ItemsSource = routesList;
        this.comboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
        this.comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;

        this.comboBox2.ItemsSource = routesList[comboBox.SelectedIndex]._stopsList;
    }

    List<BusRoute> routesList = new List<BusRoute>();
}
```

Comment: This does work as expected. So either you have some more code, or you are doing something more than what you have said or something strange is happening on your device that causes something with that file...

Comment: I've added code of BusRoute class and MainPage, so you can take a look. It's practically entire code.

Comment: Someone already answered you below. Also this isn't a proper way to write your app, you should use binding. While it is possible to do something like you did above, it is in many ways obsolete and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem here is that `GetStopsList()` is marked to run `async`. When you call `GetStopsList` in the `BusRoute` constructor, the code continues immediately, and eventually reaches `this.comboBox2.ItemsSource = routesList[comboBox.SelectedIndex]._stopsList;` At that point the `ReadLinesAsync` hasn't completed yet (execution in the constructor wasn't paused), so an empty list of data is bound to the `comboBox2`.

The reason this works when you are debugging is that when you add a break point and inspect the code you are causing an artificial delay which allows enough time for `ReadLinesAsync` to complete.

Try changing `public async void GetStopsList()` to `public async Task GetStopsList()` this will allow the caller to `await` the function. You then need to call `await GetStopsList();` before binding the data list.

You can't `await` inside the constructor, so you will need to call the intialisation function from somewhere else. This posses an interesting challenge as all your code is inside a constructor. Perhaps there is a `Page` event you can do this in, e.g. on `Load` or on `Init`.

Comment: You can't await inside a constructor (unless they changed that for C# 6)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, argh, hadn't considered that!

Comment: I put setting _combobox2_ source into page's Loaded event. It works perfectly now. Thanks a lot!